# ValueError: Lepton not connected............................... lepton not working

Tags: python, face-recognition, temperature

```
from flirpy.camera.lepton import Lepton

camera = Lepton()
image = camera.grab()
camera.close()
```

its not working and showing error
ValueError: Lepton not connected.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a misconnection. Try removing the sensor from the socket and pluggin it again. Sometimes unplugging and plugging the usb works out.